# Multiply the values in the "Enabled TextBoxes" Using JavaScript in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, controls

I have five TextBoxes such as ID of the TextBoxes are as follows:

```
     1. txtD1
     2. txtD2
     3. txtD3
     4. txtQuantity
     5. txtTotal
```

Here, the TextBoxes txtD1, txtD2 and txtD3 are Enabled Or Disabled based on the values from the DataBase. In the front end we dont know which are the TextBoxes will be enabled or disabled. In txtQuantity I want to enter the Number. Now I want to multiply the enabled TextBox values with the txtQuantity and I want to Display the value into the txtTotal TextBox. How to do this? At the same time I want to pass the textboxes as function's argument. So it will be useful, wherever we wants.

Comment: what do the text boxes comeout as, input? or textarea?

Comment: all the textboxes comeout with integer values.

Comment: Note my comment on the answer you have chosen--i.e. from @Srinivasan__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function MultiplyValues(txtBox1,txtBox2,txtBox3,txtQuantity)
{
    var ReturnValue = 1;
    if (txtBox1.disabled==false && txtBox1.value.lenth>0)
        ReturnValue *= txtBox1.value;
    if (txtBox2.disabled==false && txtBox2.value.lenth>0)
        ReturnValue *= txtBox2.value;
    if (txtBox3.disabled==false && txtBox3.value.lenth>0)
        ReturnValue *= txtBox3.value;
    if (txtQuantity.value.length>0)
        ReturnValue *= txtQuantity.value;
    document.getElementById("txtTotal").value = (ReturnValue==1)?0:ReturnValue;
}
```

The above function will able to calculate the value based up on the textbox status(enabled or disabled) and the display in the txtTotal. You can apply this function to a button *onclick*. event

@alex, Thanks for informing, I missed this case. PFB, Modified function

```
function MultiplyValues(txtBox1,txtBox2,txtBox3,txtQuantity)
{
    var ReturnValue = 1;
    var isThere = 0;
    if (txtBox1.disabled==false && txtBox1.value.length>0) {
        ReturnValue *= txtBox1.value; isThere=1; }
    if (txtBox2.disabled==false && txtBox2.value.length>0) {
        ReturnValue *= txtBox2.value; isThere=1; }
    if (txtBox3.disabled==false && txtBox3.value.length>0) {
        ReturnValue *= txtBox3.value; isThere=1; }
    if (txtQuantity.value.length>0) {
        ReturnValue *= txtQuantity.value; isThere=1; }
    document.getElementById("txtTotal").value = (ReturnValue==1 && isThere==0)?0:ReturnValue;
}
```

Comment: Note: Parameters of this function should be a element. Not value of an element. So, you can pass the ClientID to this function

Comment: You will get a `0` if the value of all the text boxes is `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onblur` event of JavaScript and call the JS method to calculate and assign the total to the Total Textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" onblur="javascript:update();"></asp:TextBox>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     function update() {
         document.getElementById('<%= txtTotal.ClientID %>').value = 
         document.getElementById('<%= txtQuantity.ClientID %>').value *
         document.getElementById('<%= txtD1.ClientID %>').value;
     }

</script>
```

Comment: Hi akhtar, I want to multiply only the enabled TextBox value with the txtQuantiy TextBox value. We came to know which textbox is enabled only after we receive values for the textboxes from the database.

Comment: let us say you are getting empty value from DB, you can add check before calculating any textbox value. e.g. if(document.getElementById('<%= txtD1.ClientID %>').value != "" )

Comment: ya. Ok. But How do we find here that txtD1 TextBox is Enabled? Suppose If txtD2 & txtD3 are Enabled and txtD1 is disabled means, We need to Multiply like this txtTotal = txtQuantity * txtD2 * txtD3.

Comment: you can try this...  if(document.getElementById('<%= txtD1.ClientID %>').disabled == "disabled")

Answer (score 1):

Can you use jQuery? If you can, use jQuery to check which ones are enabled then sum them all. I have a working sample at http://jsfiddle.net/2SfX3/

If you have html like:

```
<input type="text" class="factor" id="txtD1"/>
<input type="text" class="factor" id="txtD2" disabled="disabled"/>
<input type="text" class="factor" id="txtD3" disabled="disabled"/>
<input type="text" id="txtQuantity" />
<input type="text" id="txtTotal" />
<input type="button" id="compute" value="Compute" />
```

You can implement your jQuery as this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#compute').click(function() {
        var total = 0;
        $.each($('.factor'), function(i, data) {
            if (!$(this).attr('disabled')) {
                total = total + parseInt($(this).val());
            }
        });   
 $('#txtTotal').val(parseInt($('#txtQuantity').val()) * total);
    });
});
```

The output of this will be the first textbox value * quantity, because `txtD1` is the only one enabled.

- This is assuming you are dealing with integers. You can use `parseFloat` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

in case they are textarea you can use this to see if they are enabled

```
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');

var length = tags.length;

for (var i;i <length; i++){
   if (tags[i].disabled == false) {
     // now you can do something with this tag this enabled
     // example
     alert(tags[i].value);
   }
}
```